# Element height won't change with getBoundingClientRect()

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to resize the height of an element by using `Element.getBoundingClientRect()`.
The height of the element was logged before and after `element_box.height += 50`; where the computed height does change. Yet, the height of the element doesn't change on the page. Why does `div` height remain 120px when it's suppose to be 170px?

https://jsfiddle.net/sxm2gn48/1/

```
<div></div>
```

```
div {
  border: 1px solid;
  height: 120px;
  width: 130px;
}
```

```
let div = document.querySelector("div");

window.addEventListener("load", function(event) {
    const element_box = div.getBoundingClientRect();
    element_box.height += 50;
})
```

Comment: Because it is still 122px and the way you set height is just the value of property not actual CSS override. To override [DOM CSS](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_htmldom_css.asp) you have to use `.style.height` on DOM object. Please see the link for example.

Comment: Your [fixed](https://jsfiddle.net/m3x8ne9s/1/).